# iptables translate multicast to unicast

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, multicast

I'm attempting to translate multicast traffic to unicast to send over the Internet.

I enabled ip forwarding and tried using the following rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 239.0.0.0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.0.2.1
```

However, the traffic is never sent out.

Is there someway to do what I'm attempting without setting up a tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no.

Unfortunately Multicast is a bit special.

You also won't likely have much success passing it over an IPsec VPN tunnel.

However your best bet would be to use a GRE tunnel and if you need security you can pass the GRE tunnel through an IPsec tunnel.

A nice guide on setting up GRE on Linux : [here](http://ask.xmodulo.com/create-gre-tunnel-linux.html)